# How to stop Internet Explorer 6/7 displaying hover submenus

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

here's my website [www.colaistemhuire.org](http://www.colaistemhuire.org) 
It works fine in every browser except in IE6/7 the hover on the menus wont stay visible when I move the mouse into the submenu.

Since each of the top level menu items links to a new page with the submenus anyway, is there a quick way I can get IE6/7 to ignore the mouse hover so that when someone viewing the site in those browsers hovers over the top level menu they dont see the drop down menus at all?

Alternatively is there a fix to make those submenus stay visible?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to use javascript or jQuery's hover function. IE6/7 wont accept `:hover` on anything other than `<a>` tags (read the `<li>` you are trying).

Comment: No need for JS. he can just make all the whole class to display none in IE.

Comment: @tomca32 Sure, but that would be hiding the whole submenu. I'm telling him how he would fix it to have the submenu still work on those versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6 and 7 combined are less then 1% of all users these days. Are you sure it is worth your time?

But anyway, I would do something like that:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>     <html class="oldIE"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->


.oldIE li:hover ul {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: yeah I know its basically non existant, but the school uses it, and a few students might as well. I cant force them all to upgrade unfortunately.That looks like the answer Im gonna have to use, just a nuisance having to add it to all the pages

Comment: If are trying to avoid editing every single .html page, CSS star hack should apply only to IE7 and lower: *display:none;

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make a style only for IE, like Eugene suggested, just make it important.

```
.oldIE li:hover ul {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: i havent seen !important before, what does it mean?

Comment: !important is used to give priority to applied `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Conditional Comments

```
<head>
<title>Extra-Curricular - Col&#225;iste Mhuire Ballygar</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>
<!--[if !(IE 6)]>   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_pacthed.css" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```